# Configuring Google Groups via email

Tags: google-groups

We have a Google Group which works perfectly. It is an email-only group, meaning none of our users views posts or posts via the web interface. All posts are received through email, and sent to users via email only.

However, in order to change settings (e.g. a user wants to get each message as it is posted, and another one wants to get only one email per day, etc.) one has to use the web interface.

Is there any way to make these changes via email?

Subscription, confirmation and unsubscription are possible through email.

Are these the only email-enabled options?

Answer (score 1):

To manage their membership settings, group members should use the web user interface.

**Reference**
[My membership settings - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1047839?hl=en)